# Fluid layout doesn't work in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a simple layout with fluid values (percentages for height and width). I got a container and a wrapper, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to change the width and height values of the wrapper.

I got a wrapper with the following values:

```
div.wrapper{
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As well as a container with the same code but wider. When I remove the overflow: hidden-value, the wrapper will just becomes really thin and not actually "wrap" around any of the internal elements.

Since this is a kind of complicated problem, I posted my entire layout on JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/folaveda/1/

The problem is apparent there as well, as well as all the css that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `height` property on the ***container***, then you can set the child `.wrapper` to consume a percentage of its parent's element. Percentage `height`s and `width`s are relative to their immediate parent element's dimensions. In your scenario, the parent element is only consuming the dimensions of its children's contents, thus your perceived issue. Adjust the dimensions of the parent/s and you'll have your solution.

*note, you'll likely need to set the dimensions on the `body` and `html` element explicitly to something like `100%`, or a value that's more appropriate for your scenario.*

Comment: You will also need to put height:100% on body and html unless container has a fixed height

Comment: Alright, I tried that and now the whole thing exploded. ^^ You think you can JSBin me a version where it works?

Comment: Aight, I set the values for html as well and it worked. Thanks!